# Opacity Effect with Header & Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone please explain how you would create the effect seen on this website where the content's opacity changes to a hazy white as it gets closer to the top of the viewport? I have looked through the code, but can't get the desired effect on my own. http://www.sylvainreucherand.fr/

Comment: Set the background of a div to a linear gradient, and change the opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the effect as follows. Let me know if you have any problems.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="haze-effect">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

.haze-effect {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff,hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
  background: linear-gradient(#fff,hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
}
```

Comment: Might want to give the div a z-index of some higher value if there are any elements that have z-index applied to them on your web pages.

Comment: If you would like, you can award the answer to me :)